# SVG viewBox, rectangle, and polyline

Tags: svg, viewport, scaling, viewbox

The SVG attribute `viewBox` **appears** to be inconsistent. It **seems** it doesn't scale all SVG graphics primitives the same way. Here's a sample SVG file that has a rectangle, a `circle`, a `polyline`, and a `polygon`. The rectangle has been properly scaled and almost filled the viewPort (which has a `width` of 500 and a `height` of 500).

Please see the SVG code and image it produced below. As you will notice the `polyline`, `polygon`, and `circle` did not scale to fill the view port. They do (consistently) occupy the top-left quarter of the view port though (moved but retaining the original size). Can anyone please throw some light on what's going on with this? I will greatly appreciate your feedback.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' 
    xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
    height='499' width='501' viewBox='100 100 200 200'>
    <g stroke='BLACK' stroke-width='5' fill='none'>
        <rect x='105' y='105' width='193' height='193'/>
        <polygon points="150,100 200,200 100,200" style="stroke:purple" />
        <polyline points='115,180 155,127 180,180' stroke='red'/>
        <circle cx='150' cy='150' r='50' stroke='green'/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

[image: SVG image converted to a JPG]

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you think a circle of radius 50 should fill a viewBox which has a width and height of 200?

Comment: The same reason why the 193 by 193 rectangle filled the 500 by 500 viewport. Here's what I understood (please correct if I'm wrong). Content of the viewBox always scales to fill the view port.

Comment: the rectangle is almost 200 wide because 193 is not far from 200. The circle is 100 wide as 50 radius = 100 diameter. 100 is not well known as a number that is close to 200.

Comment: Yes, the 200 x 200 viewBox size scales to fill the 501 x 499 view port. That means that something that is 200 user units wide becomes 501px wide. Smaller things are smaller and bigger things are bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Short answer:*

The `SVG` attribute `viewBox` on the sample code **does scale all SVG graphics the same way**; so the smaller object representations **are actually smaller objects**.

---

*Explanation:*

It's useful to look at he [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) documentation to better understand the calculations. Let's try to go through you sample code step-by-step:

1. the `SVG` viewport dimensions are set to *501* by *499* (`width` by `height`)
2. the `viewBox` attributes are set as

   1. *100* for `min-x` and `min-y`, which will act like shifting the position of the viewport before its container top and left positions (which in the image it seems like irrelevant, since you **also** shifted all the coordinates by *100*;  *see my note below*)
   2. *200* for `width` and `height`, which will represent 100% of the viewport size (in this case ~`500px`); in other words, **the 200 value in any children will be mapped (scaled) into ~`500px`**
3. the `rect` has *193* as `width` and `height`, which is nearly *200*, this makes it occupy almost all of the ~`500px by 500px` viewport area
4. the other items are scaled properly, but they **seem smaller** because, in fact, they **are smaller**

   1. e.g. the `circle` has `r='50'` which would fit an imaginary outer square of *100 by 100*; 100 is 50% of 200, so it is scaled to ~250px by ~250px (250 = 50% of 500); that is why the circle seems to use 1/4 of the area
   2. the same idea is applied to the other graphic elements.

---

*NOTE:*

I found it was easier to understand the final results if there was no shift on the viewport and on the positioning coordinates. So, removing 100 from `viewBox` > `min-x` and `min-y` (step 2.1 above) and from all the positioning attributes would make this code easier to understand:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' 
        xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
        height='499' width='501' viewBox='0 0 200 200'>
        <g stroke='BLACK' stroke-width='5' fill='none'>
            <rect x='5' y='5' width='193' height='193'/>
            <polygon points="50,0 100,100 0,100" style="stroke:purple" />
            <polyline points='15,80 55,27 80,80' stroke='red'/>
            <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='50' stroke='green'/>
        </g>
    </svg>
```